# How To Terminate a Lexer in ANTLR4

Tags: antlr4

Is there a simple way to terminate a lexer?

There are some tokens that I do not want to handle yet.  But I also want the Lexer to sound an alarm if the input does contain those tokens. My simple strategy is throwing a RuntimeException in an action:

```
CHARIZING:  '#@' {throw new RuntimeException("charizing op not supported yet");};
```

But the action produces compilation error since the generated Lexer has a break command after the action and the Java compiler complains the break is an unreachable statement.

```
CPPDefineLexer.java:118: error: unreachable statement
                case 1: throw new RuntimeException("charizing op not supported y
et"); break;
```

Is there a simple strategy to terminate a Lexer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fool the compiler:

```
CHARIZING
 : '#@' 
   {
     if (true) { throw new RuntimeException("charizing op not supported yet"); }
   }
 ;
```