# antlr4 how to make rule throw exception

Tags: antlr, antlr4

in my code:

```
     andexpr : orexpr (AND orexpr)*;
 orexpr :  atomicExpression ( OR  atomicExpression)*;

 atomicExpression :
    attribute //THIS
  | equalsExpression
  | notEqualsExpression;

equalsExpression: attribute eq (value | arrayValue);
notEqualsExpression: attribute neq (value | arrayValue);
```

I want to make `THIS` rule throw exception and be invalid case. 
 I want it to be included as 'valid' to make additional context while parsing tree. And I enter only `attribute`. 
Is it possible?

Comment: just add an action to 'attribute' and have it throws an unchecked exception. But remember to precede that throw statement with an 'if (true)' to prevent compiler complaining about unreachable statement since ANTLR4 will generate something after your action

Comment: can you provide example, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your code:

```
 atomicExpression :
    attribute {if(true) {System.out.println("error");throw new RuntimeException();}}
  | equalsExpression
  | notEqualsExpression;
```

> error
>
> Problems calling org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig.main(args)

I've done a quick test, it seems that the TestRig of ANTLR v4.5.3 catches the RuntimeException itself. So it just prints a statement saying there is a problem calling TestRig.mains(args) without the usual stack trace we encounter normally after an exception. So I suggest you to add something meaningful before throwing the exception.

The `if(true)` is necessary to prevent the java compiler complaining about unreachable statement since it is smart enough to know `RuntimeException()` terminates the program but there will certainly be some code generated by ANTLR after the exception clause.

See my previous question:
[How To Terminate a Lexer in ANTLR4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22507775/how-to-terminate-a-lexer-in-antlr4)

Comment: Thank you, for explanation.